# Cannot detect a ZKTeco RFID reader when using an Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have a [ZKteco RFID reader](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Zkteco-U1000e-8924815.html). I connected it to my router via an ethernet cable and also connected my laptop to the same router via an ethernet cable as well. I have tried to connect to this reader using TCP/IP but it fails to connect. I then open NMAP and scanned all devices on my network but I could not find the reader.

Why is the reader not being detected on my network?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I figured it out! Even managed to learn abit about setting up network devices. I'm now trying something else. Trying to connect multiple acm readers like in the previous post to network and then label each reader as in or out in the software . Will post a new question if I get stuck that's related to this community :)

Comment: You should write an answer for setting it up when you get a chance! You can accept your own.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try connecting the Ethernet cable for the Reader to another port on your router just in case the issue is with the port.

Comment: The other suggestion is to contact Zkteco support and let them know about the issue you are having with the RIFD reader. It could be an issue with the device.

Comment: I found the issue. Your previous post/answer was helpful. I see ZKTeco is for access control but their software does not allow you to view the scanned RFID tag EPC or change the EPC of the RFID reader. Do you know of how I can do this?